# Emmet tab completion - unexpected results (Sublime text 2)

Tags: html, sublimetext2, emmet

I've been using Emmet with Sublime Text 2 and my tab completions have
changed and I'm not sure why.

Where I used to enter 'div' (tab) and get `<div></div>`; now I get `display: block;`

Other examples:

- 'p' (tab) was `<p></p>`; now is `padding: ;`
- 'h1' (tab) was `<h1></h1>`; now is `height: 1px;`

Based on other issues like this, I've entered the following in the Emmet User Preferences, But this has not solved the issue:

```
"remove_html_completions": true,
"disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete": false
```

Comment: Format your answer a little better, your combining code parts with text and its a little hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was in the document source code (an invalid comment inside a style tag). 
Once the source code was fixed; Emmet was back to normal.